# how to manage ruby's bundler own version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I use bundler to manage my dependencies' versions.

The question I am asking myself now, is: how to manage bundler's version itself. I mean, "bundler install/update/outdated" helps me understand what I am holding back, update them optimistically or pessimistically ... but I am not sure what's the best practice / procedure to decide about bundler itself.

In other words, is there a gem- or bundler-based workflow that ensures that I and my coworkers do use the latest (or the to-be-specified) version. Bundler gives us this workflow for all the other gems, but what about bundler itself ?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the newest version?

Comment: That's basically what I am wondering. And how to have a workflow that ensures that I and my coworkers do use the latest (or the to-be-specified) version. Bundler gives us this workflow for all the other gems, but what about bundler itself ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might be of some help to you here.

First, you need to install the appropriate version of bundler:

```
% gem install bundler -v '~> 1.12.5'
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.5
```

Then force RubyGems to use the version you want.

```
% bundle _1.12.5_ install
```

---

This pattern `gem-binary _gem-version_` works for any gem binary.

You can check the available versions for Bundler from [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions).

Comment: My question was really unclear, I've edited it to add more details about what I was looking for.